# SQLAlchemy Operational Errors

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am running a Flask application and have been getting this error when someone tries to access the application after about a day of inactivity:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
```

The app then completely stops working until it's restarted, throwing this error when the request is retried:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.PendingRollbackError: Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back. (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/8s2b)
```

I've already tried adding keepalive arguments into the connection

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app, engine_options={'connect_args': {
'keepalives': 1,
'keepalives_idle': 30,
'keepalives_interval': 10,
'keepalives_count': 5
}})
```

I also have configured the app to use the pool_pre_ping option:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {"pool_pre_ping": True}
```

And this is the query that's failing:

```
stmt = db.session.query(User).filter(User.username == username)
account = db.session.scalars(stmt).first()
```

How can I prevent these operational errors and subsequent PendingRollbackErrors from happening?

Comment: What versions of `sqlalchemy` and `flask-sqlalchemy` are you using?

Comment: Also I think you are mixing the query api with the newer `select` based api.  I think stmt should be `stmt = select(User).where(User.username == username)`.  I don't see how that would cause those exceptions though instead of just failing immediately but maybe you using some hybrid `< 2`. edit: removed extra paren

Comment: Flask==2.3.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
SQLAlchemy<2.0

Comment: It seems that you aren't closing the session properly.  flask sqlalchemy should do that but are you using sessions outside of the application context?

Comment: I'm not - but I've added a line after each query to include `db.session.close()` which should explicitly close the session. Will see if that changes anything. Thanks for the feedback!